# Grails giving sorted list to findAllByIdInList

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I dont want the result re-sorted.

Example:

```java
def ids = [7, 9, 5, 6, 12, 2, 10, 1, 42, 13]
result = Project.findAllByIdInList(ids).collect{
    projectUtil.createProjectDTO(it)
}
```

Then if I get the Ids of object created they are sorted this way

```
result = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 42]
```

I'd like to keep the same order is there a way to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: What does `projectUtil.createProjectDTO()` do?

Comment: `projectUtil.createProjectDTO()` create an Java Object called ProjectDTO    that contains only the attributes needed in my GSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `getAll` instead of `findAllByIdInList`:

```
def ids = [7, 9, 5, 6, 12, 2, 10, 1, 42, 13]
result = Project.getAll(ids).collect {
    projectUtil.createProjectDTO(it)
}
```

I just tested it with a similar example in an integration test and it returned the instances in the same order as declared in the list of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `withCriteria`

```
result = Project.withCriteria {
  'in'('id', ids)
}.collect { projectUtil.createProjectDTO(it) }
```

Comment: In terms of performance which one of the two answer is the best ?

Comment: You can enable the sql log to see the query produced. I think that they will be the same, so the difference is just how much readable the code is.